# React Js with azure storage blob

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am having problem to download a file from azure storage account, using react js. I installed @azure/storage-blob through npm install and did import it.

```
const storageAccount = '<storage-account-name>';
const sas = '<sas-token>'
const blobService = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/${sas}`
);

const containerClient = blobService.getContainerClient('<container-name>');
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('<file-name>');
blobClient.download().then(val => console.log(val));
```

when I try to use the `readableStreamBody` to download the file as mentioned in Microsoft example
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-javascript#download-to-a-string, I get access to the account but I always retrieve `readableStreamBody` as undefined.

[image]
Is there any settings that I need to configure for azure?

Thank you in advance.

I was expecting value for readableStreamBody, so I can download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are using ReactJS to download the blob (in other words using the SDK in the browser), the blob content is available in `blobBody`. From the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-javascript#download-to-a-string) you shared:

[image]

Please try something like the following:

```
// Download and convert a blob to a string
const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download();
const downloaded = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody);
console.log(
  "Downloaded blob content",
  downloaded
);

async function blobToString(blob: Blob): Promise<string> {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    fileReader.onloadend = (ev: any) => {
      resolve(ev.target!.result);
    };
    fileReader.onerror = reject;
    fileReader.readAsText(blob);
  });
}
```

Code reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-blob-blobclient-download.